# Trying to use ref inside my App component but have an error Function components cannot be given refs

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v5

I try to get access to some navigation pages when signup in the app but have the following error: **Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?** Maybe it is the way I am trying to do it, I explain:
**My App Navigation**

```
import React from 'react'
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { createSwitchNavigator } from '@react-navigation/compat';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'
import AccountScreen from './src/screens/AccountScreen';
import SigninScreen from './src/screens/SigninScreen';
import SignupScreen from './src/screens/SignupScreen';
import TrackCreateScreen from './src/screens/TrackCreateScreen';
import TrackDetailScreen from './src/screens/TrackDetailScreen';
import TrackListScreen from './src/screens/TrackListScreen';
import { Provider as AuthProvider } from './src/context/AuthContext'
import { setNavigator } from './src/navigationRef';

const Stack = createStackNavigator()
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator()

const UserScreen = () => {
  return (
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="TrackList" component={TrackListScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="TrackCreate" component={TrackCreateScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Account" component={AccountScreen} />
        {/* <Tab.Screen name="TrackDetail" component={TrackDetailScreen} /> */}
      </Tab.Navigator>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen 
            name="Signup" 
            component={SignupScreen} 
            options={{
              title: 'Sign up',
              header: () => null
            }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen 
            name="Signin" 
            component={SigninScreen} 
            options={{
              title: 'Sign in',
            }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen 
            name="UserScreen" 
            component={UserScreen} 
            options={{
              title: 'User Account'
            }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen name="TrackDetail" component={TrackDetailScreen} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}

export default () => {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <App ref={(navigator) => {setNavigator(navigator)}} />
    </AuthProvider>
  )
}
```

**My navigationRef**

```
import { CommonActions } from '@react-navigation/native'

let navigator

export const setNavigator = (nav) => {
    navigator = nav
}

export const navigate = (routeName, params) => {
    navigation.dispatch(
      CommonActions.navigate({
        routeName,
        params
      })
    );
}
```

**My API access**

```
const signup = (dispatch) => async ({ email, password }) => {
    // make api request to sign up with that email and password
    try {
        const response = await trackerApi.post('/signup', { email, password })
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token)
        dispatch({ type: 'signup', payload: response.data.token })
        navigate('TrackList')
    } catch (err) {
        dispatch({ type: 'add_error', payload: 'Something went wrong with sign up' })
    }
}
```

**I don't know how to pass the ref inside the App Component:**

```
export default () => {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <App ref={(navigator) => {setNavigator(navigator)}} />
    </AuthProvider>
  )
}
```

Comment: Only class components have `ref` by default. If you're using functional components you have to use `useImperativeHandle` and `forwardRef` as the error you're getting says. Take a look at rn documentation about `useImperativeHandle`, you'll find there a clear example of how to use it.  (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle)